How to get Paraview module to run in my my-env on Spyder
I am trying to run a python script that uses Paraview to produce the images, however I keep getting the error
runfile('/Users/kennediwhite/workspace/solar_storm/post_process_2014-02-08/H_content.py', wdir='/Users/kennediwhite/workspace/solar_storm/post_process_2014-02-08')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/spyder_kernels/py3compat.py:356 in compat_exec
    exec(code, globals, locals)

  File ~/workspace/solar_storm/post_process_2014-02-08/H_content.py:7
    from paraview.simple import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paraview'

I've re-downloaded Preview, moved it to my bins folder, and downloaded it to its own my-env but I am getting the same error. What am I doing wrong? The end result should be my csv files turned into images.

maybe Spyder uses different Python or it doesn't use your venv. Maybe it need change settings somewhere in Spyder. OR In code you can run print( sys.executable ) to get /full/path/to/python which is used to run your script and later you can use /full/path/to/python -m pip install ... to install module for this Python.
